# Property of elliptic curves with a torsion point

Tags: elliptic-curves

Let $E/\mathbb{Q}$ be an elliptic curve with a $p$-torsion point. Does this imply that $E/pE$ is isomorphic to $E$? If not, are there any conditions I can assume such that this is true?

Comment: I guess you mean a $\mathbf{Q}$-rational $p$-torsion point, i.e., $E[p](\mathbf{Q})\neq 0$. I don't know what you mean by $E/pE$. Do you mean $E(\overline{\mathbf{Q}})/pE(\overline{\mathbf{Q}})$, or $E(\mathbf{Q})/pE(\mathbf{Q})$? In the former case, the quotient is zero because multiplication by $p$ is surjective on geometric points of $E$. If you mean the latter, then the answer is no, because the quotient is finite, but $E(\mathbf{Q})$ could have positive rank.

Comment: The question seems incompletely thought-out, but my guess is that you mean that if $X$ is a $\mathbb Q$-rational point of period $p$ on $E$, you’re wondering whether $E/\langle X\rangle$ is isomorphic to $E$. Please clarify!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\def\QQ{\mathbb{Q}}$This question deals specifically with the issue of things being
defined over $\mathbb{Q}$. It assumes you are already happy with the
$\mathbb{C}$ picture, which I discuss in my other answer. In this
question, my hypotheseses are that $E$ and $E/z$ are defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, 
for $z$ a $p$-torsion point. I will show that $E$ is not isomorphic to
$E/z$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Suppose otherwise.

Let $\pi$ denote the composition $E \to E/z \cong E$. So $E$ has an
endomorphism whose kernel is $\mathbb{Z}/p$. Let $R$ be the
endomorphism ring of $E$. Note that $R$ acts on $H^0(E,
\Omega^1)$. Since $H^0(E, \Omega^1)$ is a one dimensional
$\mathbb{Q}$-vector space, this gives a map $R \to \QQ$. This map is
injective (that's a special fact about characteristic zero). So, for
any elliptic curve $E$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, the endomorphism ring of $E$
OVER $\QQ$ is a subring of $\mathbb{Q}$. Endomorphism rings of
elliptic curves are also finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, so
this shows that the endomorphism ring of $E$ OVER $\QQ$ is always
$\mathbb{Z}$. So any endomorphism defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ is of the
form $w \mapsto m \cdot w$ and has kernel $(\mathbb{Z}/m)^2$, not
isomorphic to the cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/n$. Contradiction, QED.
See Silverman, *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*, Chapter III.9 for
more on endomorphism rings of elliptic curves.

It is interesting to see what happens to the $\mathbb{Z}$ examples to make them not work over $\mathbb{Q}$. For example, let $E$ be the elliptic curve $y^2 = x^3-x$. As a complex curve, $E$ is $\mathbb{C}/\mathrm{Span}_{\mathbb{Z}}(1,i)$. The $2$-torsion points are $(\pm 1, 0)$ and $(0,0)$. The first two correspond to $1/2+\mathrm{Span}_{\mathbb{Z}}(1,i)$ and $i/2 +\mathrm{Span}_{\mathbb{Z}}(1,i)$, whicle the last one corresponds to $(1+i)/2 + \mathrm{Span}_{\mathbb{Z}}(1,i)$. Note that the last lattice is a rotation-dilate of $\mathrm{Span}_{\mathbb{Z}}(1,i)$; in other words, multiplication by $(1+i)$ maps the lattice $\mathrm{Span}_{\mathbb{Z}}((1+i)/2, 1)$ to $\mathrm{Span}_{\mathbb{Z}}(1,i)$. So, as complex curves, $E$ should be isomorphic to the quotient of $E$ by the $2$-torsion point $(0,0)$.

If I haven't made any errors, translation by $(0,0)$ is given by
$$(x,y) \mapsto \left( \frac{-1}{x}, \frac{y}{x^2} \right).$$
Define
$$X := x-x^{-1} \quad Y:= y +y x^{-2}.$$
So $X$ and $Y$ are invariant for translation by $(0,0)$, and I assert
without proof that they generate the coordinate ring of the quotient. 
They obey the relation
$$Y^2 = X(X^2+4).$$
(Exercise!) Call this curve $F$. Since $F$ has only one rational
$2$-torsion point, and $E$ has three of them, they are not isomorphic
over $\mathbb{Q}$.

They are isomorphic over $\mathbb{C}$. Specifically, let
$$X=2i x \ \mbox{and} \ Y = (2-2i) y.$$

So this is an example of a case where $E$, $z$ and (hence) $E/z$ are
all defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, where $E$ is isomorphic to $E/z$ over
$\mathbb{C}$, but where they are not isomorphic over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 2):

$\def\QQ{\mathbb{Q}}\def\CC{\mathbb{C}}\def\ZZ{\mathbb{Z}}$ I'm not sure which level to answer this question at. This answer explains the situation over $\CC$, which you should understand first before thinking about $\QQ$.

---

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $\CC$, isomorphic to $\CC/\Lambda$ for some complex lattice $\Lambda$. Then $p$-torsion points on $E$ are the cosets $z+\Lambda$ for $z$ in $\frac{1}{p} \Lambda/\Lambda$. The quotient of $E$ by the torsion point $z+\Lambda$ is the quotient of $\CC$ by the lattice generated by $\Lambda$ and $z$.

For example, if $E = \CC/\mathrm{Span}_{\ZZ}(1, i)$, then the $3$-torsion points on $E$ are the images of the eight points $\pm 1/3$ and $\pm i/3$ and $\pm 1/3 \pm i/3$. The quotient of $E$ by $1/3$ (for example) is $\CC/\mathrm{Span}_{\ZZ}(1/3, i)$. As you can see, the lattices $\mathrm{Span}_{\ZZ}(1, i)$ and $\mathrm{Span}_{\ZZ}(1/3, i)$ are NOT rotation-dilates of each other, so the curves are NOT isomorphic, even over $\CC$.

Let's see when this could happen. Let $E=\CC/\Lambda$. There is a $p$-torsion point on $E$ such that $E \cong E/z$ if and only if there is a lattice $\Lambda'$ containing $\Lambda$ with $\Lambda'/\Lambda \cong \ZZ/p$ AND such that $\Lambda = \alpha \Lambda'$ for some complex number $\alpha$. Such an $\alpha$ must be a quadratic algebraic integer, since it maps a rank $2$ lattice into itself. And, since $|\Lambda'/\alpha \Lambda'|=p$, we see that $\alpha$ has norm $p$. So such an elliptic curve must have complex multipication by a ring of quadratic algebraic integers which contains an element of norm $p$. There are only finitely many such rings, and each of them acts by CM on finitely many elliptic curves (over $\CC$).

For example, let $p=5$. The only complex quadratic algebraic integers of norm $5$ are $\pm 1 \pm 2 i$, $\pm 2 \pm i$ and $\pm \sqrt{5} i$. The only possible CM rings corresponding to these are $\ZZ[i]$, $\ZZ[2i]$ and $\ZZ[\sqrt{5} i]$. The elliptic curves which have CM by these are $\CC/\mathrm{Span}_{\ZZ}(1,i)$, $\CC/\mathrm{Span}_{\ZZ}(1,2i)$, $\CC/\mathrm{Span}_{\ZZ}(1,\sqrt{5} i)$ and $\CC/\mathrm{Span}_{\ZZ}(2,1+\sqrt{5}i)$. So there are $4$ elliptic curves $E$ over $\mathbb{C}$ which have $5$-torsion points $z$ such that $E \cong E/z$. For every other elliptic curve $E$ and $5$-torsion point $z$, we will have $E \not \cong E/z$.

---

I can think of two deeper question you might be asking: (1) If $E$ is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ and the $p$-torsion point $z$ is defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, is $E \cong E/z$ over $\mathbb{Q}$? Answer: Always NO. When I have more time, I'll try to write up a detailed answer explaining this. By the way, the situation is the same if, rather than requiring $z$ be defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, you only assume that the cyclic subgroup generated by $z$ is so defined. If you don't even assume that much, then $E/z$ needn't be defined over $\mathbb{Q}$.

(2) You could be asking for $E$ defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, for $z$ (or the subgroup it generates) to be defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ but for the isomorphism $E \cong E / z$ to be defined over $\mathbb{C}$. In that case, the answer is that your hypotheses are already very restrictive, by work of Mazur ([the case of a rational torsion point](https://planetmath.org/mazurstheoremontorsionofellipticcurves)) ([the case of a rational cyclic subgroup](https://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=482230)). It should be possible to go through the small list of cases where those hypotheses are satisfied and work out when the answer is "yes" and when it is "no", but I don't want to try that unless I am certain it is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Matt E: This is the sort of question where you usually give a characteristically excellent answer; please feel free to add or improve.